# SQL Server 2008 pivot query gone wrong with column name

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot

I have some problems regarding a pivot query. I am new to this. So look for something in the internet so I found dozens of them. So I decided to follow this [Link](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1019/crosstab-queries-using-pivot-in-sql-server/). Been practice but seems like I ran into some obvious error.

My code is:

```
select 
    risk, [Quick] AS Quick, [Brown] AS Brown, [Fox] AS Fox
from 
    (select risk, site
     from tst) as ps
PIVOT
(
  count(risk)
  for site in ([Brown], [Brown], [Fox])
  ) AS pvt
```

But it is throwing an error:

> Invalid column name 'risk'.

Basically I want to have an output like this:

```
|Foo | Quick | Brown | Fox |
| 1  | 10    | 3     | 2   | 
| 2  | 5     | 4     | 4   |
| 3  | 4     | 1     | 5   |
| 4  | 2     | 3     | 7   |
| 5  | 3     | 2     | 1   |
```

Something like that. Just counting how many there is in a specific number. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your existing query is you are using the column `risk` in your final select list as well as inside of the aggregate function.  Once you've counted the `risk` values for each `site` this is not available to display.

To get around this you can add a second version of the `risk` column to your subquery similar to the following.  You then `count` this other column of `risk` and display one in the final select:

```
select risk, [ADAB] AS ADAB, [Bahrain] AS Bahrain, [Thumrait] AS Thumrait
from 
(
  select risk, piv_risk = risk, site
  from qcqcif
) as ps
PIVOT
(
  count(piv_risk)
  for site in ([ADAB], [Bahrain], [Thumrait])
) AS pvt;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9c958/13)